# How to invoke iron ajax async after returning header in computed binding

Tags: firebase, polymer, firebase-authentication, polymer-1.0

Polymer 1.* and Firebase

How can do a async operation where `this.$$('#ironAjax').generateRequest();` is call after `return '{"Authorization": "Bearer ' + token + '"}';`? I have to return the header value and then invoke the iron-ajax request.

```
<iron-ajax
  url="[[HOST]][[LISTINGS]]?foo=foo"
  id="ironAjax"
  handle-as="json"
  headers="[[setAuth()]]",
  on-error="errorHandler"
  loading="{{ironLoading}}"
  last-response="{{listings}}"></iron-ajax>
```

---

```
 pageActivated: function(activated) {
    if (activated) {
      this.setAuth();
    }
  },
```

---

```
setAuth: ()=> {
  firebase.auth()
    .onAuthStateChanged((token) => {
      return '{"Authorization": "Bearer ' + token + '"}';

      this.$$('#ironAjax').generateRequest();  // NEED TO CALL AFTER
                                               // HEADER IS SET 

    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to handle the situation with a direct modification to the header. Hopefully this can help anyone else in the same situation:

Behavior:

```
<script>
  AuthIronAjax = {
    rawSetAuth: (user, ajax) => {
      if (user) {
        user.getIdToken().then((token) => {
          ajax.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
          ajax.generateRequest();
        });
      }
    },

    setAuth: function (ajax) {
      firebase.auth()
        .onAuthStateChanged((user)=> this.rawSetAuth(user, ajax));
    }
  };
</script>
```

---

Element it is used in. Note: iron-pages is being used with a implied host property binding `activated`:

```
observers: ['pageActivated(activated)'],

  behaviors: [AuthIronAjax],

  pageActivated: function(activated) {
    if (activated) {
      this.setAuth(this.$.ironAjax);
    }
  },
```